# Dynamically creating HTML button control and nesting i tag within it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I created a simple HTML Button within c# as

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID="myID";
btn.Click+=new EventHandler(someFunc);
```

which works perfectly fine as expected. But all I need to do is to insert an icon within it.
Similar to something like this.

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

Could someone please guide as to how to insert this within the button?

Comment: Why are you adding `i` element within button? Instead use `btn.style = "font-style:italic;"` and `btn.text = "add";` to add the text and italic style to the button, add the required class `material-icons` with the button itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `Button` you have to use `HtmlButton` and have server click event, because WebControls Button will render like `<input type` so it cannot have another control  inside it.

Also someFunc should be event not string

Following is the complete code that you can use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton btn = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton();
        btn.ID = "myID";
        btn.Attributes["class"] = "mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored";
        btn.ServerClick += new EventHandler(someFunc);
        btn.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"material-icons\">add</i>";

        // you can add your button to some other parent control or to form
        myCustomPanel.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

protected void someFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Make sure to add your button in form or some other control inside form.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `HtmlGenericControl` object and add all the relevant properties like `InnerText`,`class` etc and finally add this object to the button's controls collection. This will give you the expected output:-

```
HtmlGenericControl iTag = new HtmlGenericControl("i");
iTag.InnerText = "Add";
iTag.Attributes["class"] = "material-icons";
btn.Controls.Add(iTag);
```