# ASP.Net code behind button with font awesome icon

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, code-behind

My designer gave me this, which works great:

```
<button class="btn btn-circle btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
```

Standard html button with some bootstrap styling and font awesome icon.

However I dynamically create the buttons at runtime in a table and add them to a placeholder on the page. Now I am battling to get the font awesome icon to display. I use them elsewhere on the site where things are simpler, and the font awesome icons work fine.

Can anyone suggest how I would specify the icons on the buttons at runtime? Real world the icons will be different based on different business logic.

Sample code:

```
        void Sample()
    {
        phDirectors.Controls.Clear();
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = manager.FindById(Page.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        using (var context = new UserApplicationModelEntities())
        {
            var appId = new Guid(this.hdntbApplicationsId.Value);
            var application = context.tbApplications.FirstOrDefault(app => app.tbApplicationsId == appId);

            Table oTable = new Table();
            oTable.CssClass = "table table-striped";

            TableHeaderRow oHead = new TableHeaderRow();
            TableHeaderCell oHCell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TableRow oRow;
            TableCell oCell;

            oHCell.Text = "Name";
            oHead.Cells.Add(oHCell);
            oHCell = new TableHeaderCell();
            oHCell.Text = "Verify";
            oHead.Cells.Add(oHCell);

            oTable.Rows.Add(oHead);

            foreach (tbApplicationsDirectors oDirector in application.tbApplicationsDirectors)
            {
                oRow = new TableRow();

                oCell = new TableCell();
                oCell.Text = oDirector.FirstName;
                oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);

                oCell = new TableCell();
                Button oButton = new Button();

                oButton.ID = string.Format("{0}", oDirector.tbApplicationsDirectorsId);
                oButton.CssClass = "btn btn-circle btn-primary";
                if (oDirector.IDNumber == user.IDNumber)
                {
                    //oButton.Text = "GO";
                    oButton.Click += OButtonDirectorDetails_Click;
                    oButton.Enabled = true;
                }
                else if (oDirector.EmailSent && !oDirector.EmailVerified)
                {
                    //oButton.Text = "Resend";
                    oButton.Click += OButtonResend_Click;
                }
                else
                {
                    oButton.Enabled = false;
                }

                //I tried adding it as a literal, but to no avail.
                //Literal oIconLit = new Literal();
                //oIconLit.Text = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>";
                //oButton.Controls.Add(oIconLit);

                oCell.Controls.Add(oButton);
                oRow.Cells.Add(oCell);

                oTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
            }

            this.phDirectors.Controls.Add(oTable);

        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855705/1706450

Comment: Perfect, she works! Thanks :)

Comment: Look like this is just a tip of iceberg. How you plan to post that button back to server, and how do you know which button is clicked? The code in above link doesn't even trigger `someFunc` click event, and button disappears after clicked.

Comment: The original version of the code is longer, I just created a sample for illustrative purposes.